# How to hide or display DIV based on checkbox state on different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, checkbox

I have an app in python **django** and there's summary page with 5 sections. Lets call them A, B, C, D, E. The first three (A, B, C) are generated automatically without doing anything. while last two (D, E) are generated **based on check-box state** on a completely different page.

I am trying to use jQuery to accomplish this so far i have tried this but it only works if those DIV's are on same page. I tried googling but couldn't find any solution.

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(e){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked==true){
        //display those content
    }
});
```

I can not even pass it as **URL parameter** because i have a button on same page as check-boxes which when clicked displays the summary page in pdf format.

FYI: I am using an hidden iframe on the pages with button (Well button is also on four different pages) which have content of summary page and is shown as PDF on button click.

Comment: pass it in a cookie to each page would be the best way.

Comment: What about setting a cookie on that click and checking its presence on the onload event that happens in the page you want to hide that div?

Comment: @JoshStevens will it also work with iframe because i am not actually loading the page just using it inside iframe

Comment: You need to use either cookies or AJAX. For AJAX, perhaps when the button is pressed, pass an AJAX call to your server to do something, perhaps a database edit on the user's settings or something, and then send requests to the server every x seconds on your other page to detect if there was the change. You cannot do this directly cross-page, by nature of how HTTP works.

Comment: If your checkbox is in an iframe, you can access using contents(), like this:
$("#iframeID").contents().find("#idCheckBox)

Comment: this guy has you covered :) http://alexcican.com/post/set-cookies-javascript/

Comment: @RicardoPontual well i didnt know if i can edit the iframe, if i can than it would be much easier for me

Comment: @Nakib you don't need if the iframe is inside the page you're working.
If you're working in the iframe page, you can access the control in your parent page as well:
$('#idCheckBox', window.parent.document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a cookie easy and nice.

you can set a cookie like the below and then read it through the javascript

> set cookie:

```
   document.cookie="checkbox=true";
```

> read cookie on next page

```
   var value = readCookie('checkbox');
```

create a function which allows you to get the value back each time

```
 function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

so now when you compare it with the click you can do something like this:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(e){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checked == undefined || null){
        checked = readCookie('checkbox');
    }
    if(checked==true){
        //display those content
    }
});
```

Comment: ive just edited the bottom part so it fulfilled your checkbox if its on page or if its not. @Nakib you will obviously have to put it in click functions etc but i think you be able to easily sort that as i am not sure of your structure.

Comment: yes it did work with some tweaking based on my project. Also Some one  commented about editing the iframe content directly with jQuery. If that works then it would be much easier solution to this. But this was great solution.