# Set Cookie on Check box state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to find a way by browsing other posts to set a cookie on checkbox state. Basically, I am using toggle function in jQuery which hide some divs when checkbox is selected. When user go to other page, he need to again click on checkbox to hide those divs

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#checkbox').change(function () {
  jQuery('#ilan').fadeToggle();
});
});
```

Is there any quick way to set cookie to it for around 1 or 2 days?
Addition: [How to hide or display DIV based on checkbox state on different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479233/how-to-hide-or-display-div-based-on-checkbox-state-on-different-page) *Already tried it*

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't necessarily use cookie for this, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The `localStorage` property allows you to access a local [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object. `localStorage` is similar to [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). The only difference is that, while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the browsing session ends—that is, when the browser is closed.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  // localStorage saves text only
  var checked = localStorage.getItem('checked') === "true"; 
  
  $('#checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  $('#ilan').toggle(!checked);

  $('#checkbox').change(function () {
    $('#ilan').fadeToggle();
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    localStorage.setItem('checked', isChecked);
  });
});
```

API:

- [`.prop(propertyName, value)`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value)
- [`.toggle(display)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)
- [`.is(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector)
- [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [`.setItem(keyName, keyValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Parameters)

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked for me even in 2021.

Comment: @Chipsy I'm happy that it works for you, you should know that all values stored in {Local,Session}Storage are converted to strings, eg: `localStorage.setItem('a', false); console.log(localStorage.getItem('a')) // "false" (String) `

Comment: There is a small error in your code `var isChecked = $(this).is(':cheched');` should be `var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
With your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
      $('#ilan').fadeToggle();

      isilanVisible = $('#ilan').is(":visible");
      $.cookie("isilanVisible", isilanVisible, { expires : 2 });

    });

    if ($.cookie("isilanVisible") == false){
        $('#ilan').hide();
        $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not recheck the checkbox.

Comment: This will emit the change event and `.change(function() {...` will be fired, this will make the element `#ilan` show again in `.fadeToggle()`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You can set cookie:

```
$.cookie("myCookie", 123);
```

To delete:

```
$.removeCookie("myCookie");
```

Additionally, to set a timeout of a certain number of days (2 here) on the cookie:

```
$.cookie("myCookie", 123, { expires : 2 });
```

If the expires option is omitted, then the cookie becomes a session cookie, and is deleted when the browser exits.

To read back the value of the cookie:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("myCookie")
```